Infinite scroll with scroll position and state restoration when navigating back
I'm working on a page with an infinite list, where each item is clickable and leads to a different route. I load 10 items in a server action, I scroll down, more items load. I click one of the items, hit the browser's back button, and while the scrolling position is restored, I only see the initial 10 items that were originally rendered on the server. What's the best way to preserve all the data loaded until I navigate away from the main page?
Here's the example app.
Here's the code. It follows one of the infinite scroll tutorials, but I added the part where if you click USER LINK on any of the items, it will take you to a different page. Then when you go back, all the items beyond the initial 10 will be gone.

I don't have much experience with next.js, but it seems that you are not saving the data so when redirecting back to the page with the user list the data isn't there anymore. You should probably save the data in something like a Redux store or alternatively you might be able to work some magic with caching

@LazyJ True, I could use some global state management library, but it seems such a common use case that I'm wondering if there's something that I'm missing in Next.js itself. If it caches the scroll position, why not cache the state as well?

I don't believe the scroll position is 'cached' per se. I believe that your browser saves the scroll position in the history and since you were scrolled further than what your page allows when you return it is just scrolled to the bottom. You can use caching when fetching data to make sure that all the data is there and thus the scroll position exists. Here is a link that has info on caching in fetch calls: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating
